# Tumblr Header & Feed Spacing

Tags: html, css, tumblr, tumblr-html

I recently purchased the Margaret Studio theme from themecloset on Tumblr.

Once I added my own logo it cut off the first image on my blog with a white strip that must be the 'background' of my logo ( even though it's a transparent png). I would love to be able to fix this.

The main option I think would be to create a bigger space between my header and first post?

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to create spacing between elements vertically, I'd add a `margin-top:2%;` to the lower of the elements.

If you're able to identify the `<div>` element which you'd like to move further down, you can add some inline styling to the div:

`<div style="margin-top:2%;">`

Or if you have access to the CSS, you could add an id to the div element and add the margin that way:

`<div id="divIWantToMove">`

and in the CSS sheet:

```
#divIWantToMove {
    margin-top:2%;
}
```

You can play around with spacing using the W3 schools site :)

https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_css_margin

(obviously the 2% I've referenced here can be swapped out for any number depending on how big of a margin you're looking to create)

Comment: Hi Shane, thanks for answering! I did try your suggestion <div style="margin-top:2%;"> and it seemed to work until I published my blog. I have extremely limited html knowledge so I haven't much of an idea of what I'm doing. There's just a big white strip that I need to get rid of and the only way I see of doing that is by pushing the body of my blog further down.

Comment: Hey there - no problem at all. I don't use Tumblr so my advice is purely from a code perspective - do you have a link to your blog at all so I can inspect the HTML / CSS? (I'm not asking for access to your blog, just the web address for the frontend that your visitors will be hitting) :)